# JPA Unnecessary User class inside Transaction class

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, jpa

**User class**

```
@Entity
class User {
    @OneToMany
    List<Order> orders;
}
```

**Order class**

```
@Entity
class Order {   
    @ManyToOne
    User user;

    @OneToOne
    Transaction transaction 
}
```

**Transaction class**

```
@Entity
class Transaction {
    @OneToOne
    Order order;

    @ManyToOne
    User user; // Do you think this is necessary?

    void makeTransaction(long orderId){
        //Here I can easily get user object using orderId, right?
    }
}
```

I am very new to Hibernate. In my project, I do not understand why User user attribute got added inside Transaction class, when I am anyhow going to get User object via Order object..

**So, does above Transaction  class design wrong? or its going to create any issues later?**

Comment: Don't think it's necessary because Transaction is directly linked to Order not the user. You would be accessing the Transaction this way (User->Order->Transaction) but not the other way around.Even if you don't add the user, you can still get the User linked to Transaction through Transaction.getOrder().getUser(). So think it would be redundant to link Transaction and User again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your business requirements and business needs.

At first glance it seems totally redundant (at both side , database (redundank FK) and OO side (redundant reference).

But nothing tells me here that User in Order and User in Transaction is actually the same ...

As you explain it "seems" to be the same but personnally I don't know. So if both user can be "different" this model works.

Now if we assume the user is always the same in both concept and you have this use-case: `load transactions by some criteria (timestamp, priority, whatever) "owns" by a specific user` 
Without any "user" information in transaction you have to loop through all his orders and filter/recover transactions you need. 
With user information inside you can reach the transaction table directly (and you can even avoid loading eagerly the `Order` or just using a projection DTO).

Now maybe instead of keeping `hard reference` on `User` you could just keep a lightweigt reference on it : `private Long userId` and so decrease th risk of cyclic dependencies problem.

Now keep that in mind -> **it is still redundancy.**

In relational modeling redundancy happened when you apply some denormalization on your model and sometimes it is just required (performance-wise, use-case need, projection need...).

If you are conscious and agree with that it is ok. Just take care of `Consistency` problem that can happened and be ready to handle that property.

Comment: Hii, At first, thanks for your reply.. I got your points.. But finally, i am confused... Should I keep User in Transaction class? what would you do, for above scenario. would you keep that User in a Transaction class?

Comment: I will be glad, if you could able to tell me your opinion for this thread as well, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497853/having-multiple-exception-classes-arent-like-redundant-especially-when-we-are/61499978#61499978

Comment: as I said is it the same user ? if yes ... do you need this redundancy in your use cases ? if yes is it acceptable to only keep light reference via just the "id" ... Answer to these questions and you'll know what to do ;-)

Comment: okay... Orders depends on User and Transaction depends on Order, so indirectly YES its the same user for the same Transaction and Order. And for UI, I have a DTO (say TransactionDTO), so in TransactionDTO, I already have UserDTO to show Rest response for UI. My query related to DB only, not UI case..  and for light reference (say OneToMany or ManyToOne relationships), we mostly refer as Class only, instead of id.. (either it could be a DTO or Model class)

Comment: So, I can remove User dependency in Transaction class, right?

Comment: Thank you. could able to tell me your opinion for this thread as well, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497853/having-multiple-exception-classes-arent-like-redundant-especially-when-we-are